# How to open a message box after a shell command

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm building an app for restarting the VNC service on remote computers.

I have multiple check boxes for multiple computers; I used the following command to do the work, and it works fine.

But I need to get a `messagebox` that shows either the command completed without errors, or if any error occurred, like access denied, shows that too.

```
    If CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        Shell("psservice.exe \\192.168.1.48 -u .\user -p 123 restart WinVNC4", AppWinStyle.Hide)
    End If

    If CheckBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        Shell("psservice.exe \\192.168.1.15 -u .\user -p 123 restart WinVNC4", AppWinStyle.Hide)
    End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be using `Process.Start` over `Shell` in the first place but you absolutely need to in this case. It returns a `Process` object that will allow you to get output via a redirected output stream. Time to do some research on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub HandleService(strIP As String)

    ' Create the psservice.exe process object
    Dim p As New Process()

    ' Set it to run hidden from user, so it appears smoother.
    With p.StartInfo
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .FileName = "psservice.exe"
        .Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", "\\" &  strIP, "-u .\user", "-p 123", "restart WinVNC4")
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
    End With

    p.Start()

    Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = p.StandardError
    
    ' Read the standard error of psservice.exe and write it to console (or do your messagebox thing, etc.).
    Console.WriteLine(myStreamReader.ReadLine())
    
    ' Wait for psservice.exe to finish before we handle it's output (Sync method, manding the thread won't continue until this one is finished. Use .exited if wanting to do Async)
    ' Also note that you can add milliseconds to this if wanted. i.e. .WaitForExit(1000)
    p.WaitForExit()

End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
HandleService("192.168.1.48")
```